# How to deserialize JSON into java objects using Jackson

Tags: java, solr, jackson

I have a rather JSON response coming back from a solr instance....

```
{"responseHeader":
  {"status":0,"QTime":1,"params":{"sort":"score asc","fl":"*,score",
    "q":"{! score=distance}","wt":"json","fq":"description:motor","rows":"1"}},
        "response":{"numFound":9,"start":0,"maxScore":6.8823843,"docs":
                  [{"workspaceId":2823,"state":"MN","address1":"1313 mockingbird Lane",
                    "address2":"","url":"http://mydomain.com/","city":"Minneapolis",
                    "country":"US","id":"399068","guid":"","geo":["45.540239, -98.580473"],
                    "last_modified":"2012-12-12T20:40:29Z","description":"ELEC MOTOR",
                    "postal_code":"55555","longitude":"-98.580473","latitude":"45.540239",
                    "identifier":"1021","_version_":1421216710751420417,"score":0.9288697}]}}
```

And I'm trying to map that to a java object:

```
public class Item extends BaseModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected Integer workspaceId;
    protected String name;
    protected String description;
    protected String identifier;
    protected String identifierSort;
    protected Address address;
    protected String url;

        /** getters and setters eliminated for brevity **/
}

public class Address implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected String address1;
    protected String address2;
    protected String city;
    protected String state;
    protected String postalCode;
    protected String country;
            /** getters and setters eliminated for brevity **/
    }
```

How do I map the address1, address2, city, state, etc... into the Address object in the Item object?  I've been reading about [Jackson annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/JacksonAnnotations) but nothing really jumps out at me as to where to begin.

Comment: You have to specify what you tried. There are different approaches http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Have you considered using SolrJ? You may find that more convenient, both for unwrapping the response, and for constructing the query.

Comment: @Eric I had not but completely willing to look into it.  Do you have a URL you think is a good place to start?

Comment: @EricWilson SolrJ does have a way to map to POJOs but nothing (that I can find) to map to nested children objects like mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended up using Solrj - sort of.

We wrote our own SolrResult object that we fed to SolrJ like so:

```
List<SolrResult> solrResults = rsp.getBeans(SolrResult.class);
```

And then in SolrResult.java where we had complex or nested objects we just first used SolrJ annotation to get the field and then just set the value as needed...

```
@Field("address1")
public void setAddress1(String address1) {
    this.item.getAddress().setAddress1(address1);
}
```

It wasn't hard just feels a bit messy, but it does work.

Answer (score 2):

If using Jackson 1.9 or higher you can use the [@JsonUnwrapped](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonUnwrapped.html) annotation to handle this.

Here is an example of using it (largely lifted from Jackson's documentation):

```
public class Name {
   private String first, last;

   // Constructor, setters, getters
}

public class Parent {
   private int age;
   @JsonUnwrapped
   private Name name;

   // Constructor, setters, getters
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   try {
      final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      final Parent parent = mapper.readValue(new File(
            "/path/to/json.txt"), Parent.class);
      System.out.println(parent);
   } catch (final Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```